# Passing text file data to a variable

Tags: python

I am learning python and am having a bit of trouble with utilizing data in a text file.

As an example the text file is structured line by line like this:

```
name 656 334
```

I want to grab the data in a loop line by line and put the two integers into two separate variables like a = 656 b = 334 but I’m having trouble getting it to do that. I’ve tried various iterations of lists and numpy arrays but at most I can only get it to include both numbers together when I call on the array.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data line format is the same in whole document and the data separator is an space, you could unpack the line data with **split** like this:

```
_, a, b, = line.split()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that all of the values in each line will be separated by spaces, then you can iterate through the lines in the file and use `split` to get the values into a list, then assign them accordingly.

```
with open('my_file.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file.readlines():
        parts = line.split()
        a = parts[1]
        b = parts[2]  # or parse it as _, a, b = line.split() as lennhv said above
```

Comment: Yeah, I think `_, a, b, = line.split()` version is easier to maintain

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to extract the numbers into an array

Example code here:

```py
import re

txt = "name 656 334"
x = re.findall("[0-9]+", txt)
print(x)
```

This will return an array with the two values

```
['656', '334']
```

Then you just have to access both values of the array and assign it into a variable or use it just by accessing the array

Answer (score 0):

Run through the whole file line by line and split each line at the spaces. Something like this:

```
with open("your filename", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        name, a, b = line.split()

        #Do anything with the values here
```

This can also be done with a shorter list comprehension, but since you're starting off that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Pandas as well. I have used below code with my rating txt.

```
# import pandas library
import pandas as pd
# read rating file, without header and set column name for fields
rating_df = pd.read_csv('ratings.txt', sep=' ', header=None, names =["userId", "itemId", "rating"])

for index, row in rating_df.iterrows():
    print(int(row['userId']), int(row['itemId']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=' ', header=None)
df['function_solution'] = df[1].multiply(df[2])
```

1. Iterating through data is inefficient
2. Using a `pandas.DataFrame`, which uses vectorized operations is more efficient
3. `pd.DataFrame.multiply` is just an example.  Once your data is in the `DataFrame`, any function can be performed.